# Adding different objects into one list

Tags: c#, list

I have to code simple music player, it's exercise for override methods. I have to give artist and title name, and what kind of music that is that song.

I have classes which are the kinds of music, and one base class `Music` and now I am looking for any resolve the simplest way how to create an object like:

```
Music song = new Rock(artist, title);
Music song = new Classic(artist, title);
```

and put them in one `List<Music>`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `var songs = new List<Music>() { song }`; ... done

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a collection initializer, in order you create a `List<Music>`:

```
var songs = new List<Music>
{
    new Rock(artist, title),
    new Classic(artist, title)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that if you want some console reading and a method that plays the song.

```
public class Music {
        public string Artist { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

    public Music(string artist, string title) {
        Artist = artist;
        Title = title;
    }

    public void play(string song) {
        Console.WriteLine(song);
    }
}

public class Rock : Music
{ 
    public Rock(string artist, string title) : base(artist, title)
    {
    }
}

public class Classic : Music
{
    public Classic(string artist, string title) : base(artist, title)
    {
    }

}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Music song1 = new Rock("ac-dc", "highway to hell");
        Music song2 = new Classic("elvis presley", "love me tender");
        List<Music> list = new List<Music>();
        list.Add(song1);
        list.Add(song2);
        Console.WriteLine(list[0].Artist +", " + list[0].Title);
        Console.WriteLine(list[1].Artist + ", " + list[1].Title);
        string a = Console.ReadLine(); // just type "yeah" or whatever
        song1.play(a);
        song1.play(a);
        song1.play(a);
        song1.play(a);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```